# List<String> list = new List<String>() not working Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, list

```
List<String> list = new List<String>()
```

is not working. I'm trying to create a list of strings in Visual Studio Code using C#, but `List<String>` is not working.

The error I get is:

> Error CS0246: the type or namespace name 'List<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Include your code snippet on your question.

Comment: are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: did u add "using System.Collections.Generic" ?

Comment: There is no Visual Studio **Core** - do you mean Visual Studio **Code**, or are you talking about a **.NET Core** project in the full Visual Studio? Please clarify

Comment: I`m using only using System;
Do I have to use  System.Collections.Generic as well?

Comment: Yes, you have to add a using for the exact namespace for classes you want to use.

Answer (score 6):

You're probably (bear with me here) *missing a using directive or an assembly reference*.

Try adding:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

to the top of the code file, which is the first option (a "using directive"). You can also click on the quick-actions icon in the IDE (or press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>) and it'll usually offer to fix it for you:

[image]